# Solving whether a list acts as a sublist of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've been working on this problem for a bit and just feel totally lost. It seems like it'd be very fundamental but just can't seem to solve it. I'm not really looking for an exact answer, just rather if I'm on the right track. I just finished my 3rd week of Intro to Programming so I'm sure some formatting is a little wonky, so sorry about that.

I'm trying to define a function that can take two lists: `list1` and `list2` and see whether `list1` serves as a sublist for `list2` while also taking ordering into account.

For example, in the book the question says this:

If `list1` is defined as:
`[15, 1, 100]`

and `list2` is defined as:
`[20, 15, 30, 50, 1, 100]`

then `list1` is a sublist of `list2` because the numbers in `list1` (15, 1, and 100) appear in `list2` **in the same order.**

However, `list [15, 50, 20]` is not a sublist of `list2` because the ordering is not the same.

I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way but I'd like to attach what I have thus far and would love anyones opinion on it. I've added comments to give a bit more insight into my thought process.

---

---

```
l1 = eval(input('\nPlease enter a list of integers: '))
l2 = eval(input('\nPlease enter a second list of integers: '))

def subList(l1, l2):
    'Takes two lists as input from the user and determines'
    'True if list1 is a sublist of list2 and false otherwise.'

    newLst = []
    indexNum = 0
    result = subList(l1, l2)

    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        return False
    elif l1 == []:
        return True

    for num in l1:

        #My thinking here is that this while loop should run for as long     as ther variable indexNum
        #Doesn't exceed the length of lst2, allowing me to compare every num of lst1 with that of lst2
        while indexNum < len(l2):

            #If I come across a number in lst2, at a certain index, that's the same as lst1 I want
            #to execute the following:
            if l2[indexNum] == num:

                #I've added a blank list at the top, newLst, which I want to append the matching number to.
                newLst.append(l2[indexNum])

                #I'll also want to still add one to the indexNum variable to compare the next number in lst2
                indexNum = indexNum + 1

                break

                #If the number at lst2[indexNum] isn't equal to that of lst1, I still want to add to the
                ##indexNum variable to keep going through the loop and comparing the other items.
            else:
                indexNum = indexNum + 1

        ## I'm thinking here that if at the end of the outer loop, if my newLst is equal to the lst1, then that
        ## should mean that it works as a sub list. I could be wrong here and my thinking is way off though.
        ## If it is equal then the return value should be true, if not false.
        if l1 == newLst:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and checked your code. I have to say, it almost seems like someone purposely inserted bad lines in a perfectly nice solution:

1. You have a recursive call in the 6th line of the function. This is not only useless, but will cause the function to keep recursing.
2. That final `if...else` is also killing it. Obviously `newlst` will not equal `l1`, as by the time you get here you have only checked one element at most of `l1` - Remove it.
3. Which makes `newlst` useless.
4. **Great use of an else on while**. Do not see many good uses of this as naturally as here - nice!

**Additions from @Olivier that I missed**

5. Checking `l1` is empty is redundant - the loop will skip, and you return True
6. Before breaking, you still need to increment the counter

This is the fixed solution:

```
def subList(l1, l2):
    indexNum = 0
    if len(l1) > len(l2): return False

    for num in l1:
        while indexNum < len(l2):
            if l2[indexNum] == num: 
                indexNum = indexNum + 1
                break
            indexNum = indexNum + 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

l1 = [15,1,100]
l2 = [20,15,30,50,1,100]
l3 = [15,50,20]
print(subList(l1,l2))
print(subList(l3,l2))
```

The logic of your loop:

1. Take an item from `l1`.
2. Loop until you find it in `l2`. `indexNum` manages this well between iterations.
3. `else` if you did not find it, return `False`.
4. Return `True` if you managed to do this for all elements in `l1`.

Your solution is not only simple, it is the most efficient.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your help, especially for the thorough breakdown of the loop.

It really made it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Actually you need to make sure to increment indexNum also before breaking from your while loop. If you test with first list `[15, 1, 1, 100]` against l2 for example, your code would return True incorrectly. Also the `if l1 == []:          return True` in your code and @Coop code is not necessary, empty list means zero iteration of your for loop, and you return True anyway.

Comment: @Olivier Nice catch, missed that!

Comment: Thanks @Oliver for catching that and explaining it. Only been in class for 3 weeks but both of you explain these very clearly. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by using list comprehension and the built-in [all()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#all) to check if lists are equal

---

```
l1 = [1,3,4]

l2 = [7,9,1,2,1,3,4,9,8,1,3,4,9]

# the length of the looked for list
lenL1=len(l1)

# create all sublists of this length from each starting position of l2 up to its end
# and check if this sublist has exactly the same digits as the l1 list using all()
a = [(l2[i:i+lenL1],i) for i in range(len(l2)-lenL1) \
                       if all(l1[q]==l2[i+q] for q in range(lenL1))]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[([1, 3, 4], 4), ([1, 3, 4], 9)]
```

It found the sublist at post 4 and 9 in `l2`

---

If you rather have a "written out" method instead of a list comprehension, you can do something similar like so:

```
def checker(l1,l2):
    """Enuimerates over l2, finds a value thats same as l1[0] and delegates
    sublistchecking to inner function checkSame"""
    def checkSame(a,b):
        """gets two lists of same length and checks that theire values are identical"""
        return all(a[i] == b[i] for i in range(1,len(a))) # 0 was checked already

    l1_len = len(l1) # store length so we do not need to lookup it all the time

    for idx,value in enumerate(l2):
        if value == l1[0]:          # check 0
            if  checkSame(l1,l2[idx:idx+l1_len]):
                yield(l1,idx) 

print(list(checker(l1,l2)))
```

---

I prefer to use `enumerate(iterable)` if I need the index into something iterable alongside the value - enumerate returns both:

Doku [enumerate(iterable[,start])](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate)